Added multiple triggers for Keda from the same type Prometheus
Is that possible to have the Keda Trigger specification using multiple triggers from the same type? In this case prometheus?
  triggers:
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
         [metadata1 - related to response time]
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
         [metadata2 - related to CPU metrics]
  - type: prometheus
    metadata:
         [metadata3 - related to Memory Metric]


I added first the response time trigger and the application was scalling up and down, following the metric. After I added the other two, now it doesn't scaleup using the response time metrics.

Answer is yes. That's why it's called triggers and not trigger.

KEDA will start scaling as soon as when one of the triggers meets the
criteria. Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) will calculate metrics for
every scaler and use the highest desired replica count to scale the
workload to.


I noticed is called triggers, but it’s not working for triggers of the same type. I did not find in any place mention if that is allowed or not.
Did you manage to have this working for triggers from the same type?

I would file a bug if your prometheus case is not working. https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues
